# Where can I find a good tutorial and/or example for creating front-end forms in custom components?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, jform, form, form-fields-types

I'm building my first component for Joomla 3.x (I don't need support for 2.x). I've created my models (and unit tested them). I'm now ready to create the views. To start I just want to create a simple form to enter an address. It'll have text boxes and a drop-down list for states. Could someone point me to a tutorial and/or sample code that illustrates how to create forms and fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you need to get started with JForm for views

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/development/getting-started-with-jform/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joomla Component creator tools for basic component and if you want to learn the component structure. https://www.component-creator.com/en/